# Is it possible to not export a module in BuckleScript?

Tags: module, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Is it possible to not export certain internal modules that should not be used directly by package consumers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an undocumented option you can specify in `bsconfig.json` to whitelist the modules you want to export, but as I understand it, it will hide aliased modules too, and so is only useful to hide truly internal modules, and a bit error-prone since it's a whitelist. I've therefore not used it myself. But if you want to try it, you can specify `"public"` like this:

```
{
  ...
  "sources": [{
    "dir": "src",
    "public": ["ModuleA", "ModuleB"]
  }]
  ...
}
```

It's listed in the [bsconfig.json schema](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/docson/#build-schema.json), btw, with the useful comment:

> Default: export all modules. It is recommended for library developers to hide some files/interfaces